# Laravel 5 return view not working

Tags: laravel-5, view, routes

I am trying to return a view that is located in a subfolder of views:

[image]

I have a route that calls a controller and in the index function it returns the view:

Route:

```
Route::resource('employee','EmployeeController');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Employee;



class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
    return view('employee.index');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

When I try the following url:

```
http://cats/employee
```

I get this error message:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   2/2 ErrorException in 10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php line 14: Use of undefined constant employee - assumed 'employee' (View: C:\inetpub\vhosts\cats\resources\views\employee\index.blade.php)

```
in 10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php line 14
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\storage\\framework\\views/10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\resources\\views/employee/index.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

1/2 ErrorException in 10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php line 14: Use of undefined constant employee - assumed 'employee'

```
in 10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php line 14
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Use of undefined constant employee - assumed \'employee\'', 'C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\storage\\framework\\views\\10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php', 14, array('__path' => 'C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\storage\\framework\\views/10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag)), 'obLevel' => 1, '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in 10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php line 14
at include('C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\storage\\framework\\views\\10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\storage\\framework\\views/10f0bf4300a070310e2f44dc1b237ad9e8092472.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\cats\\resources\\views/employee/index.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Is this code giving the problem:

```
return view('employee.index');
```

Did I make a mistake unknowingly?

EDIT: here is the view that is being loaded:

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel CRUD Operations</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>All employees</span>
            <a style="float:right;" href="{{  route(employee.create) }}">Create     New Employee</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        @if ( message == Session::get('success'))
        <p><i> {{ message }},</i></p>
        @endif

        <br>
        <br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated by the error message is that you are using the `employee` variable in your `employee.index` template without passing it as a parameter to the view.

In your controller instead of `return view('employee.index');` you can first retrieve the employee detail then for example do this:

> return view('employee.index', ["employee" => $employee]);

Assuming the `$employee` variable has already been filled with the employee details

Comment: employee.index refers to the index.blade.php file contained in the /views/employee folder path. I don't have any variable whatsoever. According to the laravel documentation this way of return views is valid, simple by using the dot "." and a separator...

Comment: I am not saying that  `return view('employee.index');` is invalid but that in that template it's self you are trying to access the `$employee` variable. can you post the content of the employee.index file?

Comment: yes you are right. The problem is in the view index.blade.php. It's loading the file but it's not finding the data. Let me update my question so that I show you the view page...if this is so then you answered my question :)

Comment: on this line `<a style="float:right;" href="{{  route(employee.create) }}">Create     New Employee</a>` you use `$employee.create` but there is no employee being passed to the view

Comment: I understand. I am following a video course and the instructor for some reason was able to do it. Maybe he did not provide the necessary information, I don't know.

Comment: is {{  route(employee.create) }} a function that laravel should understand?

Comment: Yes it's a Laravel helper function. checkout [route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route)

Comment: OK I got it. I needed to add quotes like this: 'employee.index'. Thank you once again for your help